# Expo Image Picker get Image size

Tags: react-native, expo

knows everyone how I can get the file size from files picked with Expo-Image-Picker? I can't get the size with expo-filesystem. The path from Image picker is strange: file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540everyjonny%252Fpropstack/ImagePicker/142a5fd7-9284-4d2f-af08-596951d8cf53.jpg

code example:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    const uri = result.uri
    let fileName = ""
    fileName = result.uri.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
    console.log("URI;", uri)
    result = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri)
    console.log("filesize", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already did almost all the work. You can find the size from **result.size** at the last last line.

Check out the documentation
[enter link description here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetinfoasyncfileuri-options)